# Step by Step Second Order recurrence relations

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations

Hi I have the following linear relation

$S(n)= 2S (n-1)+3S(n-2)$

$S(1)  = 3$ 
$S(2) = 1$  
$S(3) = ?$

1- I know I need to find $c_1$ & $c_2$ 
Which are $c_1 = 2 $, $c_2 = 3$

2-I  Know the roots  are $r_1 =  3$ and $r_2 = -1$

3 I know that the formula for the next step is $S(1) = p+ q$
and for $S(2)$, $pr_1 + qr_2$

How do I find the value  $p$ & $q$ to get the right equation

Comment: Welcome to math.SE! Please consider taking the time to read the [faq] to familiarise yourself with some of our common practices. In addition, [this page](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020/8348) should give you a start at learning how to typeset mathematics here so that your posts say what you want them to, and also look good. As this question appears to be homework, please consider reading [this page](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/1803/8348) for information about asking _effective_ homework-related questions. Cheers!

Comment: Something wrong with that "linear relation" --- please edit. Is $n$ the same thing as $N$? What do you mean by $c_1,c_2,r_1,r_2,p,q$?

Comment: @DanielR Its not homework because I have the answer , I know that p =1 and q = 2 and eventually can be plug to S(n) = pr1^n-1 + qr2^n-1 I just want to see how p and q are calculated S(3) should be 11 and S(4) = 23

Comment: Your edit did not fix all the missing things pointed out to you.

Comment: Your question seems to only require you to find $S(3)$, which just requires you to plug in some values. Why did you include all the rest?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to solve the [linear recurrence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recurrence_relation#Linear_homogeneous_recurrence_relations_with_constant_coefficients) $S(n)=2S(n-1)+3S(n)$.

The first step is solving characteristic equation $x^2-2x-3=0$; and you found the roots $r_1=3$, $r_2=-1$.

You wrote, that you know that general solution has the form $S(n)=pr_1^n+qr_2^n$, but you have to find $p$ and $q$.

Since you know that $S(1)=p+q$, $S(2)=pr_1+qr_2$, you can simply plug the known values into these equations and you get
$$
\begin{align}
p+q&=3\\
3p-q&=1
\end{align}
$$

This is a very simple system of linear equations with unknowns $p$, $q$. You can solve this system to find out that $p=1$ and $q=2$.